# structure program giving error at compilation time

Tags: c

I am trying to make a structure but when I am assigning the value is giving me error. The code is given below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Student
{
    char name[10];
    int cont_no;
    int roll;
};

int main()
{
    // struct Employee e1,e2;
    struct Student s1, s2;
    s1.name = "Arpit";
    s1.cont_no = 12345;
    s1.roll = 20;
    s2.name = "Anjali";
    s2.cont_no = 123;
    s2.roll = 10;

    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting is:
[image]

Comment: Assignment for arrays doesn't exist in C. Use [strcpy()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) instead.